# C++ Calculations inside while loop

Tags: c++, loops, math

I'm a beginner to C++ coding and I am trying to read lines from a text file, add them into temporary variables and then do mathematical calculations with them. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the area for each iteration of the loop since at the moment it is calculating the area using the total length/width of a rectangle and the total Radius of a circle. This is specifically for the sumRecArea, sumPerimeter, sumCircArea, and sumCircumference variables.

```
inputS.open("inData_Normal.txt");

if (inputS.is_open())
{

    while (inputS >> RecHeight >> RecWidth >> CirRadius >> FirstName >> LastName >> Age >> Savings)
    {
        sumHeight = sumHeight + RecHeight;
        sumWidth = sumWidth + RecWidth;
        sumRecArea = sumRecArea + (RecHeight * RecWidth);
        sumPerimeter = sumPerimeter + (2 * (RecHeight + RecWidth));
        sumRadius = sumRadius + CirRadius;
        sumCircArea = sumCircArea + (3.1415 * CirRadius * CirRadius);
        sumCircumference = sumCircumference + (2 * 3.1415 * CirRadius);
        sumAge = sumAge + Age;
        sumSavings = sumSavings + Savings;
        sumPeople = sumPeople + 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are adding the input heights and widths instead of the sum heights and widths.

I believe you code should look like the following:

```
SumRecArea = sumRecArea + (sumHeight * sumWidth);
```

I think this is what you are asking...

The same goes for the circle area too.

```
sumCircArea = sumCircArea + (3.1415 * sumRadius * sumRadius);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a couple of those calculations by hand or in Excel and see if you're not already doing it correctly.  Otherwise use:

```
cout << sumRecArea << endl;
```

Or some variation of it to track the calculations and see which is correct: the way you are doing it now or they way ApacheCamel suggests.  By my reading of your question it seems to me either might be what you are looking for, and only you know that.